Disable Gitlab OAuth redirecting page
I am using the OAuth sign in through gitlab for my webapp and although it seems to be fully functional without any errors, there is a split second during the sign in process where you can see a plain white page with a large text "Redirecting" and a link below it. Is there any way to have this page not be displayed or am I even doing something wrong?
I could only find one post on gitlab forum that was 2 years old and didn't have a solution. I setup the sign in according to the docs on gitlab.
